# Why avast analysing C# application while running?

Tags: c#

I made a simple application using visual studio C# 2013. When I debugged it using visual studio, it worked well. But when I open it from the bin folder, my avast anti virus guard give me an error and analysing it for a few seconds. Then give the message "No error found.". After first analysis, if I closed my application and reopen it, it will not give errors. It works well. How should I stop this avast analysis. Why Avast do this thing?

[image: This is my Avast error]

Comment: What did Avast Support say?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Avast and it's behavioral scanning. The community are not experts in Avast - Avast support are the experts.

Comment: It first starts the application in a sandbox. If it's ok, it will start without the sandbox.

Comment: I found Solution
http://superuser.com/questions/555905/stop-avast-from-attacking-my-own-programs

Answer (score 4):

Avast sees your program as a new/modified executable and treats it as a potential threat.  Possibly this is because you are executing it from within `C:\Program Files (x86)\` which is not recommended for anything under development.

You could execute from another directory and set that as excluded from the Avast scans and you could consider signing your executable which might make it trusted.

Comment: No, If I run application from E:\, result is same. Every applications I made with C# are like this. In first time executing, it gives above error, but second time, not. If I debug again and open it, it gives above error.

Comment: Try nominating a development directory and telling Avast to exclude it if possible.